# Take Value of DIV and Post to Twitter

Tags: jquery, api, twitter

I'm working on a game in Jquery and would like to take the contents of a DIV (the score) and post it to Twitter:

```
    <div id="score">
    <p>You scored <span class="scoreToPost">800 points</span>!</p>
    <p>Click <a href="">here</a> to post to Twitter</p>
    </div><!--end score-->
```

And then after the user selects to post to Twitter, it would display in the Twitter pop-up box along the lines of something like:

> > @User: "I just scored 800 points in this cool game! #CoolGameTitle"

My problem is I can't figure out how to use the Twitter button API to grab the score within the span and pre-populate the Twitter field? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to parse the html to grab the score, you can use:

```
var html = $('.scoreToPost').html();

var matches = html.match(/^(\d+).*$/);
var score = matches[1];
alert(score);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfsWr/

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can interface that into Twitter's standard Tweet button code? http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton